# load show_ads.js once

Tags: javascript, adsense

So we run google ads on our sites.

And I got thinking, each ad block ( of various sizes ) loads ..

```
<script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
            google_ad_client = "ca-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            /* ad served */
            google_ad_slot = "xxxxxxxxx";
            google_ad_width = 728;
            google_ad_height = 90;
            //-->
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
        </script>
```

and other ads, of different slot ( id's ) amd sizes, on the same page also load :

```
http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js
```

each time. So a page with say three ads on, loads that exact same js file 3 times ..

Removing that script file, adding it ONCE to the head, doesnt work for us.. the ads just dont show.

So is there a method of loading that show_ads.js file just once / page load ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Google ads script utilizes `document.write()`, which means the script must be in the position in the HTML that you want the ad.

However, fear not: the *show_ads.js* file will only be downloaded by your browser once.  The subsequent `<script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">`s will load from cache.

In fact, the `Cache-Control` headers tell your browser it can load the file directly from cache for the next hour, so there should be only one trip to *pagead2.googlesyndication.com* per session, no matter how many pages are viewed.